# VB Event Handling (conversion from .NET) from a given API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb6

So I am stuck with a problem of trying to integrate an API with example code written in .NET into legacy code written in VB and the problem I am having is with Events. The example app given by with the API is using forms, however I am trying to repeat this in a console app while firing off events. There are many different event calls that I need to achieve but here is one example: 
.NET call:

```
ReplyInteract.BaseConnection conn = new ReplyInteract.BaseConnection();          
conn.BaseOnLine += Conn_BaseOnLine;
```

And here is the call

```
private void Conn_BaseOnLine(int BaseID, int BaseState)
        {
            string status = "";
            switch (BaseState)
            {
                case 1: status = "Connected:Status 1"; txtCurrentBaseID.Text = BaseID.ToString(); break;
                case 0: status = "Connection failed or closed: Status 0"; break;
                case -1: status = "Connectiontype not supported:Status -1"; break;
                case -2: status = "Invalid Base ID: Status -2"; break;
                case -3: status = "No base connected or the usb port is occupied: Status - 3"; break;
                case -5: status = "Basestation busy with another application. Please disconnect first";break;
                case -6: status = "No Reply Interact Base station. Does not work with the Interact API";break;
                default: status = BaseState.ToString(); break;
            }
            writeDebug("Base ID: " + BaseID.ToString() + " >> Status: " + status);

        }
```

I am not used to programming in VB but here is my attempt to replicate in VB

```
   Dim WithEvents conn As New ReplyInteract.BaseConnection
   AddHandler conn.BaseOnLine, AddressOf Conn_BaseOnLine
```

```
Public Sub Conn_BaseOnLine(ByVal BaseID As Integer, ByVal BaseState As Integer)
    Dim status As String

    Select Case BaseState
        Case 1 : status = "Connected:Status 1"
        Case 0 : status = "Connection failed or closed: Status 0"
        Case -1 : status = "Connectiontype not supported:Status -1"
        Case -2 : status = "Invalid Base ID: Status -2"
        Case -3 : status = "No base connected or the usb port is occupied: Status - 3"
        Case -5 : status = "Basestation busy with another application. Please disconnect first"
        Case -6 : status = "No Reply Interact Base station. Does not work with the Interact API"
        Case Else
            status = BaseState.ToString()

    End Select
End Sub
```

Now I am not sure how to actually fire the event Any ideas? Here is the full vb code I have currently

```
Module Module1
    Dim WithEvents conn As New ReplyInteract.BaseConnection

    Dim mg As New ReplyInteract.BaseManage

    Sub Main()


        While (True)

            conn.BaseIP = "200.0.0.251"
            Dim BaseOnLine As String

            conn.Open(1, "1")
            conn.License = "****"
            AddHandler conn.BaseOnLine, AddressOf Conn_BaseOnLine

        End While

    End Sub



    Public Sub Conn_BaseOnLine(ByVal BaseID As Integer, ByVal BaseState As Integer)
        Dim status As String

        Select Case BaseState
            Case 1 : status = "Connected:Status 1"
            Case 0 : status = "Connection failed or closed: Status 0"
            Case -1 : status = "Connectiontype not supported:Status -1"
            Case -2 : status = "Invalid Base ID: Status -2"
            Case -3 : status = "No base connected or the usb port is occupied: Status - 3"
            Case -5 : status = "Basestation busy with another application. Please disconnect first"
            Case -6 : status = "No Reply Interact Base station. Does not work with the Interact API"
            Case Else
                status = BaseState.ToString()

        End Select



    End Sub
```

Comment: Look at msdn asynchronous client example.  The example uses socket but youi can replace socket with any class that inherits the socket like TCPClient.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: This would appear to be tagged incorrectly - should be `vb.net`.  This code will not compile with VB6.  In addition to Etienne pointing out the AddHandler, there's a ToString method call on an Integer, and VB6 doesn't support WithEvents in a module (only forms and classes).

Answer (score 1):

There is no `AddHandler` in VB6. You have to declare your variable using `WithEvents` (which you have done) and you can add an event handler from the IDE directly using the dropdowns at the top of the code window. An empty event handler will get generated and will be named *objectname_eventname*. What you currently have, `Public Sub Conn_BaseOnLine(ByVal BaseID As Integer, ByVal BaseState As Integer)`, looks good but you can double-check that the IDE is picking it up as the event handler for your object.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57906344/can-someone-help-me-with-events-in-vb6-from-c-sharp-dll/57910060#57910060) for some extra details.